# Using auto to a variable assigned ot a function that return const ref

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20, auto

```
const className& f();
```

If I have a function that return const ref. And use it's value to assign to a variable using auto

```
auto v1 = f();
auto& v2 = f();
const auto& v3 = f();
decltype(auto) v4 = f();
```

As far as I understand all those three option will be same. But should I still prefer to write like for v3 to be explicit in my code that it's const ref? Or maybe in C++14/C++17/C++20 now there is some other preferrable way?

Or am I wrong and they are actually different?
UPDATE: so seems I was wrong. And only decltype(auto) and const auto& will make variable const ref?

Comment: No they're *not* the same. Plain `auto` will *not* include the reference. IIRC it won't be `const` qualified either.

Comment: the question you ask is purely opinion based, hence in danger of getting closed. You can rephrase it to ask a slightly different question to make it less opinion based. For example "Are v1,v2,v3 actually all the same type?" then what to use is up to you and opinions

Comment: @TedLyngmo How so? Shouldn't this deduce `const className&` for `v2`?

Comment: i have the feeling AAA does more harm than it does good. There is too little weight on the first A. I am completely fine to use `auto` a lot, but Imho we should use `auto` conciously, instead of making it the default.

Comment: The second set of examples do not use `f()`.  Is the code supposed to reflect what happens inside `f()`?  A [mcve] would be most helpful.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not according to the rules of C++20 at least (I don't remember it for earlier standards), cf. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hf35GfE71)

Comment: @Jodocus You are not testing the right thing - and I was also incorrect with my `decltype(auto)` idea. Don't know where I got that from. [Here's the test](https://godbolt.org/z/anY6EnGMP) you should perform.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, I was projecting the use of `f` there, which for some reason is not part of the question at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a function that return const ref. And use it's value to
> assign to a variable using auto

I believe you meant to initialize the variables with the function `f`:

```
auto        v1 = f();
auto&       v2 = f();
const auto& v3 = f();
```

> As far as I understand all those three option will be same.

No, they are not the same

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v1), className>);
// plain auto does not deduce reference or apply const
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v2), const className&>);
// v2 will also be const& as function returns const&
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v3), const className&>);
```

Comment: from the comments above it seems that you are wrong about v2  https://godbolt.org/z/anY6EnGMP

Comment: @Bruice Andreas suggests that OP made an error in the question and that it should have been `auto& v2 = f();` so that example doesn't apply.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh, sorry, didn't notice  that